# How to store a reference of an object inside of another class c++?

Tags: c++, object, reference

If I have the classes Register and Line, where each Register object will include a reference to a Line object, how can I write it?

```
    class Register{
    public:
       Line &line;
       Register(Line &object){
           line = object;
       }
    };
```

is this valid? If not what can I do? Thank You.

Comment: *"is this valid?"* - Would you really be asking if it was working?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, but I read that references have to be initialized, but am I not assigning? So I don't know if it would work.

Comment: You have to make sure that the `Line` object referenced in your `Register` class outlives the `Register` object, otherwise you will run into trouble.

Comment: A reference member is almost never what you want. You won't be able to copy a `Register`, and you need to be very careful about lifetimes.

Comment: You are assigning. Assignment and initialization are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference members *must* be initialized in the ctor initializer list, assigning to them in the ctor body is not the same thing at all:

```
class Register
{
public:
Line & line;
Register(Line &object)
:line(object)
{}
};
```